# Using NuGet Packages from different Source in AWS Project

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

currently, I'm developing an Alexa skill that can return work items from DevOps. For this, I'm using the Aws Toolkit for Visual Studio.

Now I want to know if it's possible to include NuGet Packages from our DevOps organization.

Basically something like this:

```
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Slight.Alexa.Framework.Models.Requests;
using Slight.Alexa.Framework.Models.Responses;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

namespace AlexaDevOpsSkill
{
    public class Function
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Searches for a work item.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"></param>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string FunctionHandler(SkillRequest input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            IOutputSpeech outputSpeech = null;
            if (input.Request.Intent.Name == "SearchIntent")
            {
                MyNuGetPackage.DevOpsItem devOpsItem = MyNuGetPackage.GetWorkItem(input.Request.Intent.Slots["Id"]);
                outputSpeech = new PlainTextOutputSpeech() { Text = $"I found the workitem: {devOpsItem.Name}" };
            }
            Response response = new Response() { OutputSpeech = outputSpeech };
            SkillResponse skillResponse = new SkillResponse() { Response = response };
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(skillResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aware, that there is a NuGet package that allows me to search for work items at nuget.org but I want to include other functions from different NuGet packages someday. This is just my current example.

When installing a Nuget Package from a different source I can't even reference it in the function.cs document.

If this is not possible with AWS, can I host my function on DevOps for Alexa to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define multiple sources for packages in the `NuGet.Config` file in the repository root (create it if it doesn't exist).

Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

    <packageSources>
        <add key="MyCompanySource" value="https://nuget.mycompany.org/repository/index.json" />     
    </packageSources>


</configuration>
```

The exact configuration you need to specify will depend on the type of your local nuget server and its configuration. The default nuget.org source is already specified by the system-wide nuget.config, therefore you don't need to add it.

Comment: Ok, I just noticed the reason I couldn't reference it. My project was a .net Core 3.1 project while my NuGet package was in .net Core 5. Seems like I need to downgrade my packages to get it to work. But it works with the nuget.config then. Thank you :)

Comment: Had issues using a private repo when deploying a lambda function - this helped!